# Prove that if $f$ has a nonzero limit at $x_0$, then there is a deleted neighbourhood where it has the same sign as the limit.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Here's what I'm trying to prove.

Let $f$ be a function such that:

$$\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L, L \neq 0$$

Then, there exist deleted neighbourhoods of $x_0$ such that $f(x)$ has the same sign as $L$.

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, we know that:

$$\exists \delta > 0: 0 < |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$$.

So:

$$|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$$

$$L - \epsilon < f(x) < L + \epsilon$$

Let $L > 0$ and $\epsilon = L$. Then:

$$0 < f(x) < 2L$$

We are guaranteed the existence of a deleted neighbourhood for this choice of $\epsilon$. So, that proves that there exists one such that $f(x) > 0$.

Now, let $L < 0$ and $\epsilon = -L$. Then:

$$2L < f(x) < 0$$

We are, once again, guaranteed the existence of a deleted neighbourhood for this choice of $\epsilon$. So, that proves that there does exist one such that $f(x) < 0$.

This proves the desired assertion.

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't see any particular problems with what you've done.

Comment: It ain't broke, so don't fix it :-)

Comment: Eyyyy words to live by. Thanks :D